# how to resolve 'argument must be a string or number' in label encoder?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My dataset(i.e. dataset_train) has 43 categorical features, and I want to apply LabelEncoder in each of the columns.
Here i got all the categorical features:`categorical_features = [features for features in dataset_train.columns if dataset_train[features].dtype == 'O']`

Now a class is created to perform multiple label encoding:

```
class MultiColumnLabelEncoder:
def __init__(self,columns = None):
    self.columns = columns # array of column names to encode

def fit(self,X,y=None):
    return self # not relevant here

def transform(self,X):
    output = X.copy()
    if self.columns is not None:
        for col in self.columns:
            output[col] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(output[col])
    else:
        for colname,col in output.iteritems():
            output[colname] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(col)
    return output

def fit_transform(self,X,y=None):
    return self.fit(X,y).transform(X)
```

Now after executing:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

dataset_train = MultiColumnLabelEncoder(columns = categorical_features).fit_transform(dataset_train)
```

It's showing me :

```
TypeError: argument must be a string or number
```

**Note that** - NaN values are also handled previously.

how to handle this situation??

Comment: Can you include the full traceback? And the value of `categorical_features`

Comment: You should just use OrdinalEncoder, with ColumnTransformer to subset the columns, instead of hacking a custom class to abuse LabelEncoder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is solved.
One of my categorical_features had just one NaN value in it.

Previously I wrote this below code to get my categorical_features containing NaN values:
`categorical_features = [ feature for feature in dataset_train.columns if dataset_train[feature].isnull().sum() > 1 and dataset_train[feature].dtype == 'O' ]`

That's why I got those features which had more than 1 missing values in its column.

That's why I faced this error.

Now, after I modified the above code to:
`categorical_features = [ feature for feature in dataset_train.columns if dataset_train[feature].isnull().sum() >= 1 and dataset_train[feature].dtype == 'O' ]`

Now I got every column even with single NaN value.

It can execute the above code for MultiColumnLabelEncoder which I mentioned in my question.

Thanks for cooperation ♥️.